# WSDL generated Apex Class output string

Tags: apex

im having trouble getting the output from my webservice which was based in an wsdl generated apex class, it brings through a simple string 'D2978' which will need to be added to a new custom field called invoiceNumber__c everytime a commandbutton is pressed however im getting "attempted to de-reference null object

```
 public String getInvoiceNumber(String invoicenumberid) {
        ws_GenerateInvoiceNumber.invoicenumberServiceSearchQuery_element request_x = new ws_GenerateInvoiceNumber.invoicenumberServiceSearchQuery_element();
        request_x.invoicenumberid = invoicenumberid;
        ws_GenerateInvoiceNumber.invoicenumberServiceResponse_element response_x;
        Map<String, ws_GenerateInvoiceNumber.invoicenumberServiceResponse_element> response_map_x = new Map<String, ws_GenerateInvoiceNumber.invoicenumberServiceResponse_element>();
        response_map_x.put('response_x', response_x);
        WebServiceCallout.invoke(
          this,
          request_x,
          response_map_x,
          new String[]{endpoint_x,
```

im then referencing this in an apex class to move the string to the custom field however this is where i think im going wrong any pointers would be huge help getting very frustrated at this

```
        private static string callWebservice(String invoicenumberid ){
        ws_GenerateInvoiceNumber.InvoiceNumberSearchServicePort soapService = new ws_GenerateInvoiceNumber.InvoiceNumberSearchServicePort();
        string response = soapService.getInvoiceNumber( invoicenumberid);
    return response;
}

    private static string callWebserviceUpdate(String invoicenumberid ){
        ws_GenerateInvoiceNumber.InvoiceNumberSearchServicePort soapService = new ws_GenerateInvoiceNumber.InvoiceNumberSearchServicePort();
        string response = soapService.incrementupdateInvoiceNumber(invoicenumberid);
    return response;
}

    public void InvoiceNumberView (String projectId) {
        this.Project = [SELECT Id, Name, InvoiceNumber__c FROM Project__c WHERE Id =: projectId];

        // callWebservice(String invoicenumberid);
        // callWebservice(string response);
         string response = Project.InvoiceNumber__c ;
        // string response =  callWebservice(String.valueof(this.project.invoicenumber__c));
        // string response;
        // Project.InvoiceNumber__c = response;


    update project;
}
```

Comment: Can you show the declaration of `this.Project` please ?

Comment: String ProjectId {get;set;} this.Project = [SELECT Id, Name, InvoiceNumber__c FROM Project__c WHERE Id =: projectId];

Comment: Yes, that I saw it in your code, but what's the type of `Project` ?

Comment: ahh sorry Project is a custom object protected project__c Project;

Comment: Did you check with the developer console that your query return a result ?

Comment: it returns the id, name but the invoicenumber__C is still null

Comment: And on the developer console, you normaly can see what the line throwing this error ?

Comment: the command button has a try catch exception which just says broke but if i remove that it errors out on the function InvoiceNumberView

Comment: `[SELECT Id, Name, InvoiceNumber__c FROM Project__c WHERE Id =: projectId];` returns a list or a single Project object ?
If so try to change the type of Project like `List<Project__c> Project`.

Comment: no luck still broke :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public vf_projectComplete(){
    this.project = [SELECT Id, Name, InvoiceNumber__c, updateBoolean__c  
                    FROM Project__c
                    WHERE Id =: projectId];
    GINC = new GenerateInvoiceNumberController(this.project.Id);
    this.productOrders = [SELECT Id, Name, Product__r.DisplayName__c, Complete__c 
                          FROM ProductOrder__c 
                          WHERE Project__c =: this.projectId];
}
```

i forgot to add the controller to the constructor this then found an error which was sorted in my wsdl

Answer (score 0):

Where you catch the exception, use the `getLineNumber()` and `getStackTraceString()` methods to determine the location of the [NullPointerException](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_exception_methods.htm).

Then examine the line in question to find the variables that could possibly be null.

If there are more than one, use something like the following immediately before the line that threw the exception.

```
System.assertNotEquals(null, variableThatMightBeNull, 'variableThatMightBeNull was the issue!');
```

Comment: rookie mistake: didnt put the apex class in the constructor there was a wsdl error :)

Comment: @ClevelandDan I'm glad you've got it sorted. I didn't see any constructor in the question. Are you able to post and accept your own answer? It will be helpful to anyone else who comes across this question and will show that it has been resolved.

Comment: Yeah no problem